# Passing string from view controller to file in Swift

Tags: string, swift, class, instance, fatal-error

In swift, I want to have the user enter a string of text in a UITextView in a particular view, then pass that string to a separate file so that I can do stuff with it.

In my PostViewController file, I have

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController {

class var sharedPost: PostViewController {
    struct Static {
        static var instance: PostViewController?
        static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        Static.instance = PostViewController()
    }
    return Static.instance!
}


@IBOutlet weak var postText: UITextView!

...
```

this creates an instance of it and puts the user's text into postText variable

In the file I want to pass it to, I have

```
class Grade {
    let string = PostViewController.sharedPost
    var newString : String!

 ...

    init() {
        newString = self.string.postText.text
```

However upon input, the program crashes and gives me a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Does this mean it's not reading in the input text? What can I do to fix this? I also tried doing newString = self.string.postText?.text but that crashed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PostViewController()` inside your `dispatch_once` creates a new object but, since it isn't part of the display, its view is never loaded and therefore its `postText` outlet isn't filled in.

Assuming your app creates a `PostViewController` that actually gets displayed, you need to get a reference to that one in order to read from the text view.

EDIT:

One approach would be to have the `PostViewController` remember which instance was most-recently presented, if any.

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController {

static var sharedPost: PostViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        PostViewController.sharedPost = self
    }

}
```

(I'm not certain whether the assignment makes more sense in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.  You might want to experiment with that.)

---

On the other hand, it seems as if we may be asking and answering the wrong question.

Doesn't it make more sense if the `PostViewController` updates a `Grade` when the user enters information rather than the `Grade` having to go fishing for it?

Comment: I am a bit confused on what that would look like. Yes, the app does create a PostViewController that gets displayed where a string is entered.

Comment: It depends on how the displayed `PostViewController` gets created.  If it's the initial view controller, then you should be able to reference it from the app delegate.  Otherwise, whatever displays it should be able to provide the reference.

Comment: I apologize, but I guess I don't understand what you mean when you say "whatever displays it will provide the reference". The view controller that I am trying to pass the string from isn't the initial view, so do you mean my UITextView? I tried PostViewController().postText.text?

Comment: How does the first instance of `PostViewController` get control of the screen?  i.e. What creates/presents it?

Comment: A segue from the initial view to the PostViewController view called "showPostVC"

Comment: Thanks. So that means I should change my string to `init() {
    newString = self.string!.postText.text`...?  The fatal error is gone but now I am getting a constraint error on `value = dictionary.map({
    newString.lowercaseString.componentsSeparatedByString($0).count - 1
}).reduce(0, combine:+)`

Comment: I would test whether `self.string` is non-nil rather than using '!'; it would avoid future crashes.  For the other problem, you should show the actual error message.  (When I see "constraint", I think auto layout...which has no connection to map/reduce.)

Comment: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.`

Comment: OK, that's an auto layout problem, not anything about the line of code you quoted.  Basically, their suggestion (1) is the best advice for fixing it.

Comment: ugh, ok. not sure why it's making it crash at that particular line then.  looking at the constraints, nothing seems to be wrong with it

Comment: Crash?  A constraint error should be a warning.  Are you sure the message and the crash are related?

Comment: yes sir, the program crashes when I enter the string and hit submit to go to the next page, and highlights that line green with a `Thead 1: breakpoint 3.1` message and gives the constraint warning in the debug box.

EDIT: actually it seems to be working now for some reason